# Python: How to call class method from imported module? "Self" argument issue

Tags: python, class, methods, import, self

I have 2 files. I know how to call a function, but cant understand how properly to call a method from imported module which has "self" as the 1st argument.

I got this error:

> TypeError: prepare() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

```
cinemas.py    

import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

class cinemas_info():

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.basic_cinemas_info(url)

    def prepare(self, url):


        url = requests.get(url)
        tree = fromstring(url.text)
        tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
        return tree

    def basic_cinemas_info(self, url):


        tree = self.prepare(url)

        for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
            city1 = city.xpath("text()")[0]
            for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
                name1 = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
                detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
                print (city1.strip(), name1.strip(), ':')
                self.detailed_cinemas_info(detailed_url)
                self.detailed_cinemas_films(detailed_url)

    def detailed_cinemas_info(self, url):


        tree = self.prepare(url)

        for street in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='address']"):
            street1 = street.xpath("text()")[0]
            for phone in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='phone']"):
                phone1 = phone.xpath("text()")[0]
                for website in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='website']/a"):
                    website1 = website.xpath("@href")[0]
                    print ('\t', street1.strip(), phone1.strip(), website1.strip())

    def detailed_cinemas_films(self, url):


        showtimes_tab_url = '/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F'
        tree = self.prepare(url + showtimes_tab_url)

        for film in tree.xpath('//div[@class="content"]'):
            film_name = film.xpath('.//a[@class="navi"]/text()')[0]
            for dates in film.xpath('.//li[contains(@class,"showtimes-day sdt")]'):
                film_dates = dates.xpath('.//div[@class="date"]/text()')[0]
                for times in dates.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li'):
                    film_times = times.xpath('a/text()')

                    if len(film_times) == 0:
                        film_times = None

                    is_3d = times.find('span')
                    if film_times is not None:
                        if is_3d is not None:
                            print(film_dates, film_name, film_times[0], '3D')
                        else:
                            print(film_dates, film_name, film_times[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cinemas_info('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!=')
```

.

```
#films.py

import requests
from cinemas import cinemas_info

def films_list():
    url = 'http://vkino.com.ua/afisha#!='
    tree = cinemas_info.prepare(url) #  <<<----Here is my call

    for films in tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li'):
        film_name = films.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/text()')[0]
        film_url = films.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/@href')[0]
        print(film_name, film_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    films_list()
```

I know that I can move "def prepare" out of class and remove "self" argument, but I want to know, what is the right way to call "def prepare" inside of a class.

Comment: You're not using the parameter `self` in `prepare()`, remove it and add `@staticmethod` one line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the definition of `prepare` has `self` in it, you can call this method either on an instance of `cinemas_info` or by passing an instance of it  and `url` to `prepare()`.

So you just need to create an instance of `cinemas_info` class and Python will itself pass that instance to `prepare()`. You just need to pass the `url`.

```
#films.py

import requests
from cinemas import cinemas_info

def films_list():
    url = 'http://vkino.com.ua/afisha#!='
    c_info = cinemas_info(url) # created an instance of cinemas_info
    tree = c_info.prepare(url) # can now call prepare() on this instance

    for films in tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li'):
        film_name = films.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/text()')[0]
        film_url = films.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/@href')[0]
        print(film_name, film_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    films_list()
```

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Comment: It seems that now I understand the concept. cinemas_info(url) makes an instance that is equvivalent to 'self' so as the second step we can pass the actual argument to the method. By the way I found that it can be done in 1 line like "tree = cinemas_info(url).prepare(url)". Thanks all of you!

Comment: Yep you can do that in 1 line also as you mentioned.

Comment: You could have also explicitly passed the instance `c_info` like `tree = cinemas_info.prepare(c_info, url)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
from cinemas import cinemas_info
```

You are importing the class definition here. Now the next line:

```
cinemas_info.prepare(url)
```

you are calling `prepare` on this class definition. What you want is to instantiate the class first, and call `prepare()` on the *instance* of the class.

```
ci = cinemas_info(url)
ci.prepare(url)  # this works
```

**EDIT**: When you call a method on a *instance*, the `self` variable is automatically populated by Python as a reference to the instance of the object, so you only need to pass in one argument to `def prepare(self, url)`.

Comment: or declare method  cinema_info as static method (if you control module cinemas)   with @static_method decorator

Comment: @martin-konecny Ive tried what you proposed, but now I have error - TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @TitanFighter I see, I've updated the answer. When you call `cinemas_info()`, you are calling the `__init__` constructor which also requires one argument. Make sure you pass that in. So do `cinemas_info(url)` instead.

Comment: init requires arguments - check cinemas.__init__  what arguments are required. But frankly spoken these are very basic things in python - maybe you should check first some python tutorial.

Comment: @MartinKonecny AttributeError: 'cinemas_info' object has no attribute 'basic_cinemas_info'
:) it appears if I remove the rest code from cinemas.py, but if I add the code back, it tells     for films in tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li'):
AttributeError: 'cinemas_info' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: @Ivan, basic solutions have been proposed already and I googled and checked them before posting my issue. As Rahul proposed below and as Martin above - I got this TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'