# Python 2.7 - How to call class method from imported module? “Self” argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, import, self

I've been looking here in the forum to try to find an answer and the most similar I found was this: [Python: How to call class method from imported module? “Self” argument issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233691/python-how-to-call-class-method-from-imported-module-self-argument-issue) . But it does not solve my problem.

I have 2 script: 1- X and 2-Y. I need to import some def () from Y to X and here's my code where I import and instantiate:

X Script -  it I have a variable called `txtCorpus` which is the one I intend to manipulate

```
import Y
from Y import PreProcessing
txtCorpus
def status_processing(txtCorpus):
    instance = PreProcessing() #Here is where to instantiate the class contained within the Y script and where it has some defs that I need
    myCorpus = instance.initial_processing(txtCorpus)
#After some other lines of operation ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    status_processing(txtCorpus)
```

Now the Script Y

```
class PreProcessing():
     @property
     def text(self):
        return self.__text

     @text.setter
     def text(self, text):
         self.__text = text

tokens = None
def initial_processing(self):
#Operations
```

When I execute the way it is there, the following error is shown:

```
TypeError: initial_processing() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

When I do this `myCorpus = instance.initial_processing()` , the following error is shown:

```
AttributeError: PreProcessing instance has no attribute '_PreProcessing__text'
```

What is the way I have to instantiate for the code to work when I pass `txtCorpus` as a parameter?

Comment: `from Y import Y-class` that is not valid syntax. Please copy paste your code properly.

Comment: @AlexHall I'm pretty sure that is not a copy and paste error.

Comment: `from Y import Yclass` followed by the line `txtCorpus` is still definitely wrong.

Comment: `from Y import PreProcessing` I used it this way to try to leave it generically. It was not a copy and paste error

Comment: @AlexHall
I have edited so as not to generate further confusion.

Comment: @LeandroS.Matos it's not complicated. I should be able to copy the code you put here into files and see the same errors you posted. Try it now. You won't get those errors. You'll get a NameError for having `txtCorpus` just sitting in a line on its own. Where did the `class` declaration go?

Comment: @AlexHall Variable text Corpus is a specific variable that receives a text file. You can check here [Script X](http://pastebin.com/bXkBLFqZ) and here [Script Y](http://pastebin.com/ifd0bBGF). The complete code. I tried some solutions that appeared below, but I still have an error in specific. If you can, check it to see more detail. 

Edit: 
I used the name of the scripts I put here in the post, but the name of the class is another, only, to make the subject more global

Edit 2: The code is on my mother language, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include a complete exampl, but the error you're seeing here `TypeError: initial_processing() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` is because you define `initial_processing` as such:

```
def initial_processing(self):
```

Which only takes 1 argument (the class instance). Then, you pass it two arguments (the `instance`, and `txtCorpus`):

```
myCorpus = instance.initial_processing(txtCorpus)
```

Think of class methods like this:

```
instance.initial_processing(txtCorpus)
# equivalent to
initial_processing(instance, txtCorpus)
```

So you pass 2 arguments but only define the method to process 1. Hence, you need to define it to take two arguments:

```
def initial_processing(self, txt):
# code here
```

Comment: Ok. I change the  `def initial_processing(self):`  to  `def initial_processing(self,text):` 
So I invoked the method `myCorpus = instance.initial_processing(txtCorpus)` and 
I received this error: `return self.__text
AttributeError: PreProcessing instance has no attribute '_PreProcessing__text'
`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that your function is not a part of the class you think it is. You should indent it so that it is a part of the class, and add an argument for it to accept (the txtCorpus).

```
class PreProcessing():
     def __init__(self):
         self.__text = None

     @property
     def text(self):
        return self.__text

     @text.setter
     def text(self, text):
         self.__text = text

     tokens = None # Not sure what this is for...?
     def initial_processing(self, txt):
          #Operations
```

Comment: Ok. I change the `def initial_processing(self):` to def `initial_processing(self,text):` So I invoked the method `myCorpus = instance.initial_processing(txtCorpus)` and I received this `error: return self.__text AttributeError: PreProcessing instance has no attribute '_PreProcessing__text'`

Comment: @LeandroS.Matos It sounds like you never created the instance variable `__text`. Try doing so in your constructor, like by adding the `__init__` method I just edited my answer with.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that when defining you need to put in 2 arguments, one for self and one for txtCorput

```
def initial_processing(self, txt):
  # Operations
```

Y file:

```
class PreProcessing():
     @property
     def text(self):
        return self.__text

     @text.setter
     def text(self, text):
         self.__text = text

  tokens = None
  def initial_processing(self, corpus):
    # Operations
```

There is nothing wrong with your X script (except that you are importing Yclass not PreProcessing ^^)